# How to bypass CRFSMIDDLEWARE error via POST to Amazon S3?

Tags: django, upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, csrf

I am having a problem (with csrf) executing a direct upload to S3 using a POST.

Here is the code:

```
<form action="https://mymediaurl/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{{ access_key }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost/">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="{{ policy }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{ signature }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
    <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

    File to upload to S3:
    <input name="file" type="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
</form>
```

Here is the error:

```
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>
    Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: csrfmiddlewaretoken
</Message>
```

Source code that includes the csfr:

```
<form action="https://mymediaurl/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style='display:none;'><input type='hidden' id='csrfmiddlewaretoken' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='123412341234' /></div>
    <div style='display:none;'><input type='hidden' id='csrfmiddlewaretoken' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='123412341234' /></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
    <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="ASFDFDSF">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost/">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="asdhfkajewhlfawe">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="asdfasdfasdf">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
    <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

    File to upload to S3:
    <input name="file" type="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
</form>
```

I have tried adding csrfmiddlewaretoken to my policy document, but that does not work.  Has anyone ran into this problem and found a solution?  I have searched high and low but can not seem to find an answer to this specific problem.

Running Django 1.3.1 for this project if that matters..

Comment: Why dont you use s3boto storage or django-storage which have very good integration to AWS? This way, you set the AWS key, etc in a settings file, and not have to deal with it in every form

Comment: @karthikr thanks for the reply.  i am actually using s3boto at the moment, but i wanted to try and skip a local storage and send these files directly to s3.  the files are all in the neighborhood of 200+ MB and I don't want to hit my server.

Comment: Sure your policy formatted `csrfmiddlewaretoken` properly? Specifically, I'm thinking of the `$` mentioned here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=188006

Comment: @Christopher thank you for the tip and link.  I added `["starts-with", "$csrfmiddlewaretoken", ""],` to my policy document - and the upload worked.

Comment: @Lonoshea, I am in a similar position, trying to pass a custom value during this upload process. May I ask you, how did you receive the value of csrfmiddlewaretoken in your server once the success action redirect is performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with help from Christopher's comment.

Here is my policy document:

```
{"expiration": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"conditions": [
    {"bucket": "media.somehost.com"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"],
    ["starts-with", "$csrfmiddlewaretoken", ""],
    {"acl": "private"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://localhost/"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]
]
```

I just needed to add the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` to my policy with the correct format.